# push_back a vector of vectors into a vector

Tags: c++, vector

How to create a vector of matrices (vector of vectors) where the matrices are of different size and initialized?

```
typedef std::vector<double> Vector;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> Matrix;

Vector v;
std::unique_ptr<Matrix> m = std::make_unique<Matrix>();
(*m)[0][0] = 1.0; 
v.push_back(m);
```

Compilation error:

```
vectors.cpp: In function 'int main()':
vectors.cpp:37:18: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<double>::push_back(std::uniq
ue_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<double> > >&)'
     v.push_back(m);
                  ^
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you mean to push back `v` onto `m` instead?

Comment: There's no point in the unique_ptr. vector is already a rather thin wrapper around heap memory, with fast move semantics. The additional indirection doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: I want a vector of matrices: v=[ m1, m2, m3, ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something along the lines of:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> Matrix;
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Matrix>> MatrixVector;

std::unique_ptr<Matrix> m = std::make_unique<Matrix>();
MatrixVector mv;
mv.push_back(std::move(m));
```

Comment: You need to `move()` `m`

Comment: I'm trying to understand what is the difference between the solutions proposed. Using move() with unique_ptr I'm passing the pointer by reference to the vector and m is no longer accessible directly. Instead, by using a shared_ptr I'm still able to access the pointer m directly and from the vector?

Answer (score 1):

Change type `Vector` to:

```
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Matrix>> Vector;
```

then you can `push_back` it,

```
v.push_back(std::move(m));
```

BTW: `(*m)[0][0] = 1.0;` is UB. You might use `push_back` to add element.

Comment: You need to `move()` `m`

Answer (score 0):

Arrange your `typedefs` thus:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> Matrix;
typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Matrix>> Vector;
```

Note the use of `shared_ptr` - this makes it easier to transfer ownership of the `Matrix` into the `Vector`.

Then:

```
Vector v;
std::shared_ptr<Matrix> m = std::make_shared<Matrix>();
// Add content to the matrix... 
v.push_back(m);
```

Comment: The matrix m was created for the initialization of the vector, therefore, after the creation of the vector I dont need anymore the matrix m. The move() with unique_ptr is the appropriate solution for me.